# clear command not found - Yocto core-image-base

Tags: linux, yocto, busybox

I'm building `core-image-base` on **i.MX 8MM EVK from NXP**. This build is based on Yocto Zeus branch and when I'm entering `clear` command it's not available.

```sh
root@imx8mmevk:~# clear
-sh: clear: command not found
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using busybox, you can add the command with the menuconfig of it.

Comment: I'm using busybox but certain commands are missing in the image (like sed, vi, clear, mkfs, fdisk - all of these are enabled in .config)

Comment: Are you sure you're using that .config file. I would expect some defconfig file you your meta-layer.  Anyhow 'bitbake -c menuconfig busybox' should help debugging it.

Comment: Yes, I've updated it with menuconfig

Comment: The menuconfig task does not provide a persistent outcome. If something triggers a rebuild of busybox (dependency of busybox has changed for example), the result of the task has evaporated. It's your duty to take the resulting .config and add it to the busybxox recipe via a bbappend or create a config fragment and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `busybox` is not enabled in your distro, you could receive these similar kind of error. To resolve, add the following lines in your `local.conf`:

```sh
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " busybox"
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " busybox"
```

*Thank you community, for letting me figuring this out!*